# EFS can't be mounted on EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-vpc, amazon-efs

I'm trying to mount EFS system on my EC2 instances.
I have followed this [Walkthrough](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/wt1-getting-started.html) very well. But It seems that the EFS is not mounting by using DNS.

When I use IP it works but I don't find the files created by instance 1 inside the mounted folder in the instance 2. I mean the EFS is not realy shared. 
Please Help?

For information, DNS settings are enabled in the VPC. 
EFS and EC2 are in the same VPC.

EFS security Group has ingeress rule that allows the EC2 Security group on the port 2049.

What else should I check?

```
root@ip:~# mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 $EC2_AVAIL_ZONE.fs-4644458f.efs.$REGION.amazonaws.com:/ /efs-mount-point
mount.nfs4: Failed to resolve server eu-west-1a.fs-4644458f.efs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com: Name or service not known
root@ip:~#



root@ip:~# mount -a -t nfs4
mount.nfs4: Failed to resolve server eu-west-1a.fs-4644458f.efs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com: Name or service not known
root@ip:~#
root@ip:~# mount -a
mount.nfs4: Failed to resolve server eu-west-1a.fs-4644458f.efs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com: Name or service not known
root@ip:~#
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom DNS, you may need to redirect DNS queries to AWS DNS server:

```
echo "server=/amazonaws.com/169.254.169.253" > /etc/dnsmasq.d/amazonaws.com.conf
echo "prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;" >> /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
service dnsmasq restart
service network restart
```